# Firebase change value in an array inside a document

Tags: arrays, firebase, object, swiftui

I have a collection called movies and a document for each movie.
Among other variables is an array named "reviews" which contains an id, reviewText and so on...

is it possible to change the value of reviewText?

My thinking is something like:

```
db.collection("movies")
        .document(movieId).setData([
            "reviews[indexID].reviewText" : "new text"
        ])
```

it's the **reviews[index].reviewText** I'm unsure about, how do I tell firebase to change the reviewText in the review with the index: indexID

Hopefully you understand the question, it's hard to formulate.

Comment: Most likely this article called, [How to update an array of objects in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073) will help.

Comment: I've already looked at that and it didn't help... Seems to be outdated maybe?

Comment: It's not. I personally wrote it and the solution still works.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I am so into swiftui right now I didn't realise it's a different language. I'll try to "translate" the code into swiftui. thank you for the answer (and your patience)